# Variation of scanf()

Tags: c, scanf

Is it correct to use **scanf()** as follows:

```
int n;
scanf("[%d]", &n);
```

If so, what does it do?

Comment: Executed a sample code, but no errors were thrown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It reads a square bracket (the `[`), then a converts a decimal integer and stores the result in `n`, then reads a closing square bracket. The brackets themselves are simply skipped over, they're not part of the conversion.

You might be thinking of the character group conversion specifier, which looks like `%[...]`, where the ellipsis should be replaced by characters to accept. See the [manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf) for details.

Comment: Any specific purpose behind, that...?

Comment: Thanks. The above link falls under Linux, and it works in Windows too. So, it isn't only for Linux. Right...???

Comment: `scanf` is a standard function, @user980411, so it ought to work the same across platforms.

Answer (score 2):

```
scanf("[%d]", &n);
```

Will extract the int a a given line if the string is something like:`[1234]`  It will extract the value 1234 and store it in the int.